# PHP while loop issue in iOS 5 Safari

Tags: javascript, php

I have a while loop that do some things with a usleep() function inside loop, like this:

```
    $x = 0;
    while ($x < 30)
    {
        $x += 1;
        usleep(200000);
    }
    echo 'done';
```

This script is called by ajax in a background by this way:

```
    (function test() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/jq_test/txt.php',
            data: {text: $('#input').val()},
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#table tbody').append(data);
                setTimeout(test);
            }
        });
    })();
```

The problem i get is that safari keeps page loading bar stay active while loop is in progress. Only when x equals 30, page stops loading and echos 'done'. After that script is called in background as i supposed it to and echos 'done' each 30*0.2s. Why this happenes?

Comment: loading icon because page is loading content from ajax call. So, what's the problem?

Comment: @Jasen all the other browers execute first loop in background while safari not. thats the problem

Comment: Do you mean that no other javascript can run while the request is active?  or do you have some other definition of "not background"

Comment: @Jasen if you have firebug, i have an example [here](http://guild.oac-live.com/jq_test/) of what i mean "in background"

Comment: the `setTimeout` line is different. on that form

Comment: @Jasen did some tests, forgot to delete '50'. Unfortunately, it doesnt change anything

Comment: mybe usinf `onLoad` instead of `ready` to launch the loop will help.

Comment: @Jasen :( nope, nothing changed

Comment: I'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the problem in. Ajax was requesting a .php file that contained a `while` loop. Since this script was called kinda same time the page itself was, safari 5 understood it as a part of main page and didnt finish page loading until loop done.